# How to standardize data with different dilution factors and minimum values for each dilution factor?

Tags: statistics, bioinformatics, data-mining, variance, standardization

I have been having trouble running statistical analysis on a dataset from a mouse experiment. The dataset is derived from 3 different dilution factors (1:10, 1:20, 1:40) with each having different minumum threshold values of detection (5, <10, <20 respectively). Here is how the dataset looks with both a mix of threshold values and non-threshold values.

1st column contains the dilution factors and 2nd column contains the values of interest.

[image]

I was wondering if there is a suggested method to standardize these values despite having different threshold values. I appreciate all feedback since this is a complicated issue.

I have tried to standardize all values to 1:40 dilution factor by multiplying values corresponding to 1:10 by 1/4x and values corresponding to 1:20 by 1/2x. This solution creates enough variance in the dataset to run statistical analysis but there are obvious issues since there are some known values that drop below the threshold of detection.

I have also tried to standardize the minumum threshold of detection values to 20 and then repeated the method above. However, this leads to a lack of variance within the dataset, which does not give us as meaningful insights as we would like to see from the dataset.